# How to get a count of a repeating specified value in a column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called "file" with one column and 350 rows which contain the names of different cities. I want to see how many times "paris" is listed in the column. I don't want to do table (file) because that shows a count of all the cities; I just want to see the frequency of which Paris was repeated in that column.
I want it to look something like: Paris 46

Comment: How about `sum(df$city=='Paris')`?

Comment: If it's just one column you don't need `$city`, just `sum(df == "paris")`

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with `sum(df$city == 'paris')`?

This code runs for me:

```
df <- data.frame(city = sample(c('paris', 'london', 'cincinnati'), 350, replace = T))
sum(df$city == 'paris')
```

**Update:** You could also simply subset the data frame in the call to `table()` as long as the column is a character and not a factor.

```
> df <- data.frame(city = sample(c('paris', 'london', 'cincinnati'), 350, replace = T), stringsAsFactors=F)
> table(df[df$city == 'paris',])

paris 
  115
```